# Python Colormap

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I'm using Python 2.7.5 on Debian. 
What exactly does `cmap=plt.cm.gray` do? If gray represents a grayscale color map then how is it that I am able to display color images using this command?

```
plt.imshow(im,cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably are providing `imshow` with an `MxNx3` array, which is then interpreted and displayed as a RGB image. Any cmap provided is then simply ignored, consider this example:

```
image = np.random.rand(10,10,3)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize=(8,6))

axs[0].set_title('RGB image with gray cmap')
axs[0].imshow(image, interpolation='none', cmap=plt.cm.gray)

axs[1].set_title('Single layer image with gray cmap')
axs[1].imshow(image[:,:,0], interpolation='none', cmap=plt.cm.gray)
```

[image]

Comment: I forget "*cmap* is ignored when *X* has RGB(A) information" in the docs